# No login possible after Jenkins downgrade from 2.154 back to 2.152

Tags: security, jenkins

We faced difficulties with the com.offbytwo.jenkins Jenkins API accessing our Jenkins which has been updated from 2.152 to 2.154 last week, so we decided to return to the previous installed version, via that option in the configure Jenkins page. Jenkins restarted and no user was able to log in after this!

No hints in the logs - just the message on the login screen, that the user or password are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

We recovered our Jenkins from our backup - and it is working alright now - again in version 2.152.

Maybe it happened because of the renaming of the user folders in security fix 2.154.

Just to let you know...

Comment: Further updates worked fine then